# Java mail encoding non english characters

Tags: java, email, encoding, internationalization

Using the code below i can send an email written in non-english and although the subject appears correctly the body appears as gibberish.
Any ideas?
Thank you

```
public void postMail(String recipient, String subject, String message, String from) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

            //Set the host smtp address
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.infodim.gr");

            // create some properties and get the default Session
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            // create a message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            // set the from and to address
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

            InternetAddress addressTo=new InternetAddress(recipient);
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            msg.setSubject(subject);

            msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
            Transport.send(msg);

        }
```

Comment: How did you set the subject to encode utf-8 then?

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
msg.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

**Edit** Changed to `text/plain`.

Comment: should be "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\""

Comment: This is a very good guess and probably close to the correct solution.  We can only guess which character set your email is in.  If you don't know, either, perhaps you can add a few lines of hex dump of a sample to the question.

Comment: @wds: Edited to say `text/plain`.  The quotes around the charset identifier are completely optional so I didn't change that.

Comment: I edited these two lines:  message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8"); message.setContent(body, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");, but my gmail inbox still looks gibberish.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
```

I would write

```
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-7");
mp.addBodyPart(mbp);

msg.setContent(mp);
```

I guessed `ISO-8859-7` from your name because this charset is for Greek, but maybe you can choose it more properly. Or maybe also `UTF-8` works for your case.

Comment: Why do you need a multipart to wrap a single body part?  That's just silly.

Comment: maybe because I took the snippet from an application that sends also attachments?.. I'm a newbie with Java mail.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, try changing an encoding of your source files (including .java files) to UTF8.
In Eclipse it is done via Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
I had CP1252 as a default for my text files.

I am getting my text from .properties files. Changing them to UTF8 didn't help.
This is insane, but switching my .java files to UTF8 solved my issue!