# Fix the names of file attachments

Tags: java, email, encoding, playframework, jakarta-mail

I have a quartz `cron` job that polls email messages from a server during a specific interval. It goes recursively, and extracts all the attached files and saves them.

It works well with 95% of them, but sometimes, I get emails, whose attachments' names come encoded in a different format, for example:

```
=?windows-1252?Q?This_is_nice?windows-1252?Q?=2Em4v?=
```

And i am pretty sure that they look Ok, when they are being sent

How can those garbled file names be converted to readable text again, so I can set the file names properly?

I am using basic JavaMail functionality (Part.getFileName())

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the characters in the file names could not be represented in the encoding used in the email message. Are you explicitly setting a text-encoding for the message, if not try setting it to UTF-8 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543589/java-mail-encoding-non-english-characters).

Answer (score 0):

There's some serious corruption going on there.  What program is sending these messages?  It almost looks as if some program tried to encode the filename twice.  Possibly it's some spammer trying to trigger some bug in Windows.

In cases like this, you pretty much have to resort to heuristics.  When you get the exception, you can extract the raw header and try whatever you want to decode the header.  If the filename is being corrupted in a predictable way, you might be able to undo the corruption and then use MimeUtility methods to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not corruption. I suggest you use a regex to detect and clean the file name if the charset and encoding of the file name is specified.

> "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047